# fail2ban fails to start ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, fail2ban

I have used this tutorial to install fail2ban for my Ubuntu 16.04 server.

After going through this I tried to start with: /etc/init.d/fail2ban start

Here was the response:

```
[....] Starting fail2ban (via systemctl): fail2ban.serviceJob for fail2ban.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status fail2ban.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

failed!

When I then run: `systemctl status fail2ban.service`

I get this:

```
> fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-05-15 14:01:38 UTC; 1min 40s ago
Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
Process: 4468 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -x start (code=exited, status=255)

May 15 14:01:38 tastycoders-prod1 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
May 15 14:01:38 tastycoders-prod1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
May 15 14:01:38 tastycoders-prod1 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 15 14:01:38 tastycoders-prod1 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 15 14:01:38 tastycoders-prod1 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 15 14:01:38 tastycoders-prod1 systemd[1]: Stopped Fail2Ban Service.
May 15 14:01:38 tastycoders-prod1 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 15 14:01:38 tastycoders-prod1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
```

Answer (score 0):

Some tutorials at DigitalOcean contain errors. Check your `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`. Try to keep it as simple as you can, i.e. keep there only those options you want to change.

Otherwise, if you have copied `jail.conf` to `jail.local` (according to the guide at DO), then delete or comment out pam section, if you do not use it,  in `jail.local` file.

Go to line 146 of /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

```
# [pam-generic]

# enabled  = false
# pam-generic filter can be customized to monitor specific subset of 'tty's
# filter   = pam-generic
# port actually must be irrelevant but lets leave it all for some possible uses
# port     = all
# banaction = iptables-allports
# port     = anyport
# logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
# maxretry = 6
```

More details are here: https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1396